# Request Post not allowed for controller, but get works

Tags: spring-boot, controller

I have a spring-boot with a cors. I want set a static page controller,
I want return a static html page for same post/get request.

The get request works, but with the post request i have :
{
    "timestamp": 1563296215801,
    "status": 405,
    "error": "Method Not Allowed",
    "message": "Request method 'POST' not supported",
    "path": "/test"
}

My code :

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class StaticPageController implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/test").setViewName(
                "test");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "test", method = { RequestMethod.GET,
            RequestMethod.POST })
    public String test() {
        return "test";
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("folder/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

}
```

With the post request, my breakpoint in 'return "test";' is fired. But after i have a 405 error...

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

You are facing the issue because along with configuring the GET endpoint for `/test` , you have also configured the `ViewControllerRegistry`  to return the view `test` to `/test` url.

The `ViewControllerRegistry` is configured whenever you want to serve a static content without the need of a controller. So , try removing that and your controller method should work as expected because by default only GET is supported by `ViewControllerRegistry`.

> - Assists with the registration of simple automated controllers    pre-configured with status code and/or a view. ViewControllerRegistry 
>     registers view controller.
> - We need not to create actual controller class when using    ViewControllerRegistry. It is used when we just need to map a URL
>     with a view. addViewController(String urlPath): It adds a view
>     controller for the given URL.
> - This method returns ViewControllerRegistration and using    ViewControllerRegistration.setViewName() a corresponding view is
>     mapped. addRedirectViewController(String urlPath, String
>     redirectUrl): It maps a URL to another URL to redirect on it. It has
>     been introduced in spring 4.1.
> - addStatusController(String urlPath, HttpStatus statusCode): It maps a    URL with given status code. It has also been introduced in spring
>     4.1.

Try  using :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class StaticPageController implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @RequestMapping(value = "test", method = { RequestMethod.GET,
            RequestMethod.POST })
    public String test() {
        return "test";
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("folder/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

}
```